# gcc won't vectorize simple loop

Tags: c, gcc, auto-vectorization

I'm trying to vectorise simplified version of Example 4 from the gcc [auto-vectorize documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/tree-ssa/vectorization.html#using). For the life of me, I can't work out how to do it;

```
typedef int aint __attribute__ ((__aligned__(16)));
void foo1 (int n, aint * restrict px, aint *restrict qx) {

  /* feature: support for (aligned) pointer accesses.  */
  int *__restrict p = __builtin_assume_aligned (px, 16);
  int *__restrict q = __builtin_assume_aligned (qx, 16);

  while (n--){
    //*p++ += *q++; <- this is vectorized                                                                                                                                                                   
    p[n] += q[n]; // This isn't!                                                                                                                                                                            
  }
}
```

I'm running gcc 4.7.2 with
    gcc -o apps/craft_dbsplit.o -c -Wall -g -ggdb -O3 -msse2 -funsafe-math-optimizations -ffast-math -ftree-vectorize -ftree-vectorizer-verbose=5 -funsafe-loop-optimizations -std=c99

And it replies with:

```
Analyzing loop at apps/craft_dbsplit.c:388

388: dependence distance  = 0.
388: dependence distance == 0 between *D.9363_14 and *D.9363_14
388: dependence distance  = 0.
388: accesses have the same alignment.
388: dependence distance modulo vf == 0 between *D.9363_14 and *D.9363_14
388: vect_model_load_cost: unaligned supported by hardware.
388: vect_get_data_access_cost: inside_cost = 2, outside_cost = 0.
388: vect_model_store_cost: unaligned supported by hardware.
388: vect_get_data_access_cost: inside_cost = 2, outside_cost = 0.
388: Alignment of access forced using peeling.
388: Vectorizing an unaligned access.
388: vect_model_load_cost: aligned.
388: vect_model_load_cost: inside_cost = 1, outside_cost = 0 .
388: vect_model_load_cost: unaligned supported by hardware.
388: vect_model_load_cost: inside_cost = 2, outside_cost = 0 .
388: vect_model_simple_cost: inside_cost = 1, outside_cost = 0 .
388: not vectorized: relevant stmt not supported: *D.9363_14 = D.9367_20;

apps/craft_dbsplit.c:382: note: vectorized 0 loops in function.
```

Comment: "I'm running gcc 4.7.2" You may need to update it, it's pretty old. Newer versions do vectorize the loop.

Comment: although gcc built-in vector is pretty broken but you can give it a try

Comment: For what it's worth: given `while(n--)`, then `*p++ += *q++;` is not equivalent to `p[n] += q[n];`. The second version iterates backwards.

Answer (score 1):

The loop runs from high addresses to low addresses. Your gcc treats vector-operations as running from low addresses to high addresses, and thus doesn't realize it can vectorize. Your "optimization", making the loop a `while (n--)`, is actually preventing the more relevant optimization. Try

```
#include <stddef.h>

void foo1 (size_t n, int *restrict px, int const *restrict qx)
{
  int *restrict p = __builtin_assume_aligned(px, 16);
  int const *restrict q = __builtin_assume_aligned(qx, 16);
  size_t i = 0;
  while (i < n)
    {
      p[i] += q[i];
      i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just make a non-obscure loop: `for (size_t i=0; i<n; i++)`.

Comment: @Lundin: Lots of ways to skin a cat.

Comment: Yeah, you can either use a cat-skinning knife, well-known and immediately recognized by all cat-skinners, or you could use something else :)

Comment: Lundin, EOF, Thanks for your input. I tried the `for` loop and gcc said: `not vectorized: unsupported data-type`. I note that the `while (--n)` is the pattern from example 3 of the [gcc auto-vectorization documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/tree-ssa/vectorization.html). I suspect the ancient version is to blame. I'll try to get a new one and see what happens.

Comment: @freddofrog: If you actually read the example *carefully*, you would notice that **it doesn't iterate backwards**. It does not start at `p[n-1]` and end at `p[0]`, it starts at `p[0]` and ends at `p[n-1]`. Do you *see* the difference?